# C# Preprocessor Directives linked to solution configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio I can manually define a directive for debug using

```
#define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Release version");
#endif
```

Is there a way to link this to the solution configuration so when I select Debug/Release or a custom configuration it will auto define?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Properties->Build->Conditional compilation symbols.
Define your directives and use in preprocessor conditionals.

Comment: I don't see **Build** tab in project **Properties**? I also don't see it in solution properties. Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 here. Do I miss something?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, Which type of project do you have?

Comment: I tested console and web applications.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, If you use VB, you can find "Custom constants" in Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options...